# Get Jenkins Master Private IP address from Slave

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ip-address, cicd

I need to access Jenkins Master API over Private Subnet from a Slave Node using Groovy of the Pipeline. How can I figure out Jenkins Master Private IP Address. I was searching for that and able to see an examples of getting Slaves Addresses from Master.

I'm currently able to achieve it with AWS CLI:

```
IP_ADDR=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=jenkins-master' \
  --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress')
```

But I do not want to rely on AWS CLI presence nor Instance Name

Comment: You can access information defined in the Jenkins Server config such as **Jenkins URL** but there is no place storing the private IP, unless the URL contains it.